# HTTP Error 302 infinite loop error even though it is accessible in Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to access a link using urllib.request but its showing this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 744, in http_error_302
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code,
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
```

I tried many ways but cannot access it, it works with normally when opened in chrome though.

A code for reference is-

```py
import urllib.request

url="###"
webUrl  = urllib.request.urlopen(url)   
data = webUrl.read()        
print(data)
```

I tried using the cookies method but still it doesn't work :'(

P.S please, if you can, suggest a "not so fishy website" for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this seems to be because the 302 error which is supposed to return a redirect list returns an empty list instead. I think this is an unusual attempt to block scripts access. You can mimic a browser using a `user-agent` string in a session. I am using the requests module because it's easier

```py
import requests as req

url = "###"

session = req.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'})

r = session.get(###)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

You can see the empty 302 response with this script

```py
import requests as req

r = req.get(###, allow_redirects=False)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.url)
print(r.history)
```

Don't forget to close the tcp connection when you are done with `session.close()`